# How to draw a image like home-based shape with fixed size in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw a image like below.

http://enterprise-now.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ValueChain.png

My database has followed a record.

```
1, Inbound Logistics, Operations, Outbound Logistics, Marketing & Sales, Service
```

And I try to show as HTML document like this.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td background="arrow.gif">Inbound Logistics</td>
<td background="arrow.gif">Operations</td>
<td background="arrow.gif">Outbound Logistics</td>
<td background="arrow.gif">Marketing & Sales</td>
<td background="arrow.gif">Service</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

However, each lengths of innerText are different, so I want to fix the size of images automatically but I don't know how. It seems that the background option doesn't have image-fixed function. (Do I need to use JavaScript in order to get the size of innerText?)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you could wrap the text to the next line as shown in the example provided.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I am trying to code right now based on your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would style the table using CSS.

I have not tested this code, but you could do something like this:

```
<script>
  .arrow {
      background-image: 'path/to/your/pic/arrow.gif';
      width: 100px;
      height: 70px;
  }
</script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="arrow">Inbound Logistics</td>
<td class="arrow">Operations</td>
<td class="arrow">Outbound Logistics</td>
<td class="arrow">Marketing & Sales</td>
<td class="arrow">Service</td>
<td class="vertical" rowspan="5">Margin</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">Infrastructure</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">Human Resource Management</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">Information Technology</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">Procurement</td></tr>
</table>
```

And adjust the `width` and `height` parameters properly to achieve the size you want. For the vertical text of the word *margin*, you could do something like what they suggest in [this article](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/vertical.html) or in [this one](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/721811-solution-display-text-rotated-90-vertically-firefox-css)

Good luck!

Comment: Fixed it by using CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a width on the td's so that they remain a constant width.

http://jsfiddle.net/4g8jX/

```
table { width: 80%; }
/* 5 tabs, so 20 percent width */
td { width: 20%; text-align: center; }
```